# Scraping data using Python, requests, Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a scraper with Python, requests, and BeautifulSoup, and I have problem with two data sources that I want to scrape. I do everything like I have for other data sources that I scrape successfully.  I use the same methods, but in these cases it just doesn't work.

Here are examples:

Example 1:

Piece of html to scrape:

```
<h2 class="mgn2_14 m9qz_yp meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 mp4t_0 m3h2_0 mryx_0 munh_0 mj7a_4"><a class="mgn2_14 mp0t_0a mgmw_wo mj9z_5r mli8_k4 mqen_m6 
l1fas l1igl meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 _6a66d_LX75- m9qz_yq " href="https://allegro.pl/oferta/hp-probook-650-g5-i5-8gen-8gb-512gb-fhd-win-10-13384792874"
 title="">HP Probook 650 G5 i5-8gen. 8GB 512GB FHD WIN 10</a></h2>
```

My code:

```
url = 'https://allegro.pl/kategoria/laptopy-491?price_from=1400&price_to=5000&order=n&p=3'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
# results = soup.find_all('h2', class_="mgn2_14 m9qz_yp meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 mp4t_0 m3h2_0 mryx_0 munh_0 mj7a_4")  # I tried also this
results = soup.find_all('a', class_="mgn2_14 mp0t_0a mgmw_wo mj9z_5r mli8_k4 mqen_m6 l1fas l1igl meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 _6a66d_LX75- m9qz_yq ")

for result in results:
    print(result['href'])
```

The output for results is: `[]`

Example 2:

Piece of html to scrape:

```
<span class="ml-text-medium ml-text-color-secondary ml-pagination__count">z 694</span>
```

My code:

```
url = 'https://allegrolokalnie.pl/oferty/q/laptop'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('span', class_="ml-text-medium ml-text-color-secondary ml-pagination__count")

for result in results:
    print(result.get_text())
```

The output for results is also: `[]`

What is different in these cases?  I scraped over a dozen similar sites using methods like what I pasted above and it always worked before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be scraping the class wrong, I would use `attrs={'class': 'class-name'}`
so...

```py
results = soup.find_all('h1', attrs{'class': "mgn2_14 mp0t_0a mgmw_wo mj9z_5r mli8_k4 mqen_m6 l1fas l1igl meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 _6a66d_LX75- m9qz_yq "})
```

Comment: Hey, @walker I use that way scraping class usually and it works. I tried your version nad it still doesn't work. Output is []

Comment: Try outputting the html from the request and see if you can even find that element

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I checked that, and html from requests doesnt contain one of those elements, but I found another piece of html with data that I`m looking for and this is the solution:
Example 2:
html:

```
<div data-mlc-listing-bottom-pagination='{"has_next_page":true,"has_previous_page":
false,"next_page_url":"/oferty/q/laptop?page=2","page":1,"pages_count":694,"previous_page_url":
"/oferty/q/laptop?page=0"}'></div>
```

solution:

```
url = 'https://allegrolokalnie.pl/oferty/q/laptop'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = json.loads(soup.find('div', {'data-mlc-listing-bottom-pagination': True})['data-mlc-listing-bottom-pagination'])['pages_count']
print(result)  # 694
```

Example 1:
but example 1 still doesnt work, if I print soup there is a piece of thml:

```
<h2 class="mgn2_14 m9qz_yp meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 mp4t_0 m3h2_0 mryx_0 munh_0 
mj7a_4"><a class="mgn2_14 mp0t_0a mgmw_wo mj9z_5r mli8_k4 mqen_m6 l1fas l1igl meqh_en mpof_z0 
mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 _6a66d_LX75-" href="https://allegrolokalnie.pl/oferta/dell-14i76-gen16-gbssd-1tbdotyk-krypto" 
title="">DELL 14'-I7-6 gen./16 gb/SSD 1TB-DOTYK ,KRYPTO!</a></h2>
```

And it contains: href="https://allegrolokalnie.pl/oferta/dell-14i76-gen16-gbssd-1tbdotyk-krypto" which I want to scrap but

```
results = soup.find_all('a', class_="mgn2_14 mp0t_0a mgmw_wo mj9z_5r mli8_k4 mqen_m6 l1fas l1igl meqh_en mpof_z0 mqu1_16 m6ax_n4 _6a66d_LX75- m9qz_yq ")

for result in results:
    print(result['href'])
```

return [] And I still dont know why ;)